# <id> attribute not working in php code

Tags: php, tags

I'm trying to get the Start Slideshow link to start a slideshow with the image scrolled to the top of the page. I've got an id tag here:

```
$photobody[]='<span id="slide"></span><img src="'.$photourl.'/'.$photo.'" width="'.$size[0].'" height="'.$size[1].'" border="0" alt="" class="imageborder" />';
```

and a snippet of code here:

```
if (isset($album)) { $photobody[]="<a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?album=".urlencode($album)."&amp;p=".$photo."&amp;slide=1#slide\">Start Slideshow</a>\n"; }
            else { $photobody[]="<a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?p=".$photo."&amp;slide=1#slide\">Start Slideshow</a>\n"; }
```

The code runs, but the photo is not at the top of the page. Why isn't the id tag working?

===========

I moved the span id="slide" 
out of $photobody[] to above the `<table>`. Works now.

Comment: It works. Is it your first PHP Script? Looks like you don't understand difference between PHP and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=0;URL=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?album=".urlencode($album)."&amp;p=".$photo."&amp;slide=1#slide";
```

The id attribute it's not related to PHP it's related to the browser so when you request the url when #id and the page have the same id the browser will show this id block, otherwise the browser will not show this id block if the page have multi tags with same id

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve? *try this + code* isn't really a good answer.

Comment: what are you trying to ask !! the id attribute it's not related to PHP it's related to the browser so when you request the url when #id and the page have the same id the browser will show this id block, otherwise the browser will not show this id block if the page have multi tags with same id

Comment: Then put that in the answer - don't just leave it as *try this*